# While Loop Error for Prime numbers

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args)
{       
    int value;      
    int check = 2;
    boolean flag = true;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Number of times:");
    value = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 2; i <= value;i++ )
    {
        while(check <= i/2)
        {
            if(i%check == 0)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            check++;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");

        }           
    }

}
```

The output always prints: multiples of 3 and 5

Program prints 2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15

I want to know why it happens, because when I dry run it, it does not pick up 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `check` and `flag` for each value of `i`, inside the for-loop. Otherwise, once it has found a composite number it will go on treating numbers as composite.

Comment: Yep, it would also help if checks terminal were sqrt, not i/2, but that's not needed for correctness

Answer (score 1):

make the below changes in your code

```
 for(int i = 2; i <= value;i++ )
{ 
    check = 2; flag = true;
    while(check <= i/2)
    {
        if(i%check == 0)
```

Every times the fr loop runs the value of check and flag remains which was there in earlier iteration because of which you're getting this behavior